# disable all hyperlink on html page for 10 second using php or java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html

**disable all hyperlink on html page for 10 second using php or java script or jquery**

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: php is server side .... so use javascript / jquery

Comment: use setTimeout in jquery. At what condition (onload/onclick/hover) will you want to disable?

Comment: why do you put <input> in your example? Are you not referring to <a href=...=>?

Comment: When would you want to disable hyperlinks ? What are your hyperlinks (inputs, a, other) ? We need more explanation and more code to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setTimeout function.
For more detail ( http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/ )

setTimeout( "$(a).attr('disabled', true);",3000 );

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery is quite easy. Copy this block in the head of page.
This example disable all link (`<a...>`) and `input` tag for `submit/reset/button`(s).

```
    <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        // at start disable...
        $("a,input[type=button|reset|submit],button").prop("disabled", true);
```

```
       setTimeout(function() {
           // after 10 seconds...
           $("a,input[type=button|reset|submit],button").prop("disabled", false);
       }, 10000);

    });
    </script>
    </head>
```